# Issue in DBT models

Tags: dbt

:34:51
13:34:51  Finished running 1 Table model in 0 hours 0 minutes and 5.06 seconds (5.06s).
13:34:51
13:34:51  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
13:34:51

13:34:51  Compilation Error in model tr100_m001 (models\ldb\tr100_m001.sql)
13:34:51    No materialization 'Table' was found for adapter bigquery! (searched types 'default' and 'bigquery')
13:34:51
13:34:51  Done. PASS=0 WARN=0 ERROR=1 SKIP=0 TOTAL=1

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to answer your question if you included code from the model that is failing to build.

But based on the error message, I suspect your `config` for this model is incorrect. The name of the materialization is `table`, not `Table` (with a capital "T").

In `tr100_m001.sql`:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table') }}
```

Or in `tr100_m001.yml`:

```yaml
version: 2
models:
  - name: tr100_m001
    materialized: table
```